# JavaScript функция не передает значение переменной

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, почему переменная s стала undefined?

```
let s;
async function getId() {
    const instance = await axios.create({

        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'fields': 'id,login,name,email'
        }
    });
    instance.get(proxyurl + url)
        .then(response => {

            for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                s = response.data[0].id
                console.log(s)
                return s;
            }

        })

}
getId().then(as(s));

function as(s) {
    console.log(s)

}
as(s)
```

Comment: В аргументе чтоли где в консоль выводится? Сначала срабатывает функция, потом возвращается s. Да и даже если s вернуть в нужный момент. Та s что возвращается не та же самая что у функции в аргументе

Comment: В функции as() она уже undefined

Comment: Ну вот опять же не нужно инициализировать `let s;`. `getId()` уже вернёт нужное значение

Comment: `getId().then(v => { тут можно использовать v });` v - это ответ от getId, тоесть наш s;

Comment: Не хочет... undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз вызывается асинхронная функция, то нужно и ждать ответа от этой функции прежде, чем вызывать другую

```js
async function getId() {

  let s = 'qeqqe';
  return s;
}

function as(s) { console.log(s); }

getId().then(as);
```

---

В вашем примере сначала вызывается `getId()`, затем сразу вызывается функция `as()` с пустым аргументом, именно поэтому s - undefined.

`return s` возвращает `s` в `getId()` уже после вызова `as()`

---

```
async function getId() {

    let s;

    const instance = await axios.create({
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'fields': 'id,login,name,email'
        }
    });

    instance.get(proxyurl + url).then(response => {

        for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            s = response.data[0].id
            console.log(s)
        }
    });

    return s;
}

getId().then(as);

function as(s) {

    console.log(s);
}
```

---

Можно использовать callback

```
(async function(callback) {

    const instance = await axios.create({

        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'fields': 'id,login,name,email'
        }

    }).get(proxyurl + url).then(response => callback(response.data));

})(as);

function as(json) {

    json.forEach(item => console.log(item.id));
}
```

Comment: [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: Внес изменения, но ничего не меняется. s видна только в цикле..

Comment: @Serjik85 тогда нужно инициализировать s перед циклом и вернуть после него

Comment: @Serjik85 `console.log(response.data[0].id)` данные-то есть?

Comment: Да, данные есть, вот, что выводит консоль. 
undefined axio.js:21 
2-24207

Comment: Нет, библиотека работает

Comment: @Serjik85 обновил ответ, попробуй callback, вместо обещаний. Видимо из-за  `instance.get` s не входит в области видимости. Это будет лучшим решением, так как в цикле перебор данных и после первого return цикл остановится. А с callback каждые перечисляемые данные будут вызвать функцию as

Comment: @Serjik85 если есть возможность, можешь написать мне в телеграме и там разберёмся с проблемой. Все ссылки есть у меня в профиле.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде есть несколько неувязок:

1. Вы используете асинхронную функцию, но не возвращаете из неё ничего, поэтому по умолчанию она возвращает Promise, который разрешается в `undefined`. Вам стоило поставить `return` перед `instance.get()`, чтобы потом ожидалась вся цепочка промисов.
2. Вы зачем-то используете цикл и возвращаете значение из первой же итерации, сразу прерывая цикл. Если вам нужно вернуть несколько значений, возвращайте массив. Если одно, не используйте цикл.
3. `then(as(s))` — в `then()` нужно передавать функцию, а вы вместо этого вызываете функцию и передаёте её возвращаемое значение, то есть тоже `undefined`.
4. Обычно советуют не смешивать `async/await` и обычные методы промисов типа `then`. Внутри async функции используйте await. Попробуйте так (если вам нужно вернуть одно значение):

```
async function getId() {
    const instance = await axios.create({
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'fields': 'id,login,name,email'
        }
    });
    const response = await instance.get(proxyurl + url);
    const s = response.data[0].id;
    return s;
}

getId().then((s) => { as(s); });

function as(s) {
    console.log(s)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Переменные созданные внутри функции остаются внутри функции. А `let` и вовсе остаётся, грубо говоря, внутри любых фигурных скобок где был объявлен.

Это называют [областью видимости](https://habr.com/ru/post/78991/)

Переменную можно заготовить заранее придав ей видимость вне функции.

Вторая ошибка состоит в том что в `as` не передаются аргументы.

```
let s;

async function getId() {
    const instance = await axios.create({

        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'fields': 'id,login,name,email'
        }
    });
    instance.get(proxyurl + url)
        .then(response => {

            for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                s = response.data[0].id
                console.log(s)
                return s;
            }

        })

}
getId();

function as(s) {
    console.log(s)

}
as(s)
```

Comment: Ну так при вызове as() всё равно undefined будет

Comment: Объявил перед функцией - то же самое..

Comment: @Doofy да, заметил после нажатия отправки ответа.

Comment: @Serjik85 ответ обновлён, проверь снова

Comment: Ничего не изменилось